# Message framework: no module messages

Tags: django, django-apps, django-contrib

I am following this tutorial:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

but I get this error:

```
Error: No module named messages
```

.

And in django/contrib folder effectively there isn't a messages app.

How can I get work message framework ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message framwork is added in the development version and will be available in django 1.2, so you could download the latest svn version or the 1.2 Release candidates (preferable). More info on this can be found [here](http://www.djangoproject.com/download/).

In django 1.1 (current stable version), a less advanced message framework coupled more tightly to the user model is used, you can find more info about that [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#messages).